# JqGrid prevent checkboxes from double clic event

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid, double-click

I'm using a JqGrid with `multiselect : true` and i'm using double clic event to launch an edit function.

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                var rowData = $(this).getRowData(rowid);
                document.location.href = "../record/" + rowData['id']
            },
```

But when it comes to select multiple rows, if you select or deselect the checkbox too quickly it launches the edit function (which I do not want).

How can I prevent the dblclick event on the checkboxes and allow it anywhere else on the rest of the row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
   if ($(e.target).is("input")) {
       return;
   }
   var rowData = $(this).getRowData(rowid);
   document.location.href = "../record/" + rowData['id']},
```

Comment: Perfect !  As usual